# How to place duplicate elements from a list into an array?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I need to find duplicate items in the collection and put them in an array.

I wrote this method:

```
String[] mass = new String[(int) limit];

        for (int i = 0; i < duplicates.size(); i++){
            for (int j = 1; j < duplicates.size(); j++){
                if (i != j && duplicates.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(duplicates.get(j))){
                    mass[j - 1] = duplicates.get(j);
                }
            }
```

I have this collection:

```
List<String> duplicates = new ArrayList<>();
        Collections.addAll(duplicates, "java", "JaVa", "mm", "Mama", "ss", "MaMa");
```

But when I display the result on the screen, I get this answer.

```
JaVa
MaMa
Mama
```

What did I miss?

Comment: What does the `words` list contain?

Comment: Its duplicates list

Comment: If list has string occured multiple times then you want to collect it to array@Mefisto_Fell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things, the inner loop just needs to look forward so `j` can start at `i+1` and because of this the outer loop is ending at `i < duplicates.size() -1`. Then you can't use I or j when assigning to `mass`, you need a separate counter for this

```
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < duplicates.size() -1; i++){
    for (int j = i + 1; j < duplicates.size(); j++){
        if (duplicates.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(duplicates.get(j))){
            mass[k] = duplicates.get(i);
            k++;
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you like to do this by using java-8 streams

1. First stream the `List` into `Map`, with key as `String` and values is `Long` count of occurrence

---

```
 Map<String, Long> result =  duplicates.stream().map(String::toLowerCase)
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),Collectors.counting()));
  System.out.println(result);    //{ss=1, mm=1, java=2, mama=2}
```

2. Then filter if occurrence is greater than 1 and collect it as `String` array, below code shows combining both

---

```
String[] array = duplicates.stream().map(String::toLowerCase)
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),Collectors.counting()))
          .entrySet().stream().filter(entry->entry.getValue()>1).map(Map.Entry::getKey).toArray(String[]::new);

   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));  //[java, mama]
```

Comment: Thats great, but how it can be collect to List<Pair<String, Long>>?

Comment: but why you need `List<Pair<String, Long>>`? and on what basis? @Mefisto_Fell

Comment: which one `List` or `Array`? @Mefisto_Fell

Comment: First one with List

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to give it away, since it looks like you are learning.  Hint: you can (and perhaps should, for practice) accomplish this task with one loop.  No need to use a nested loop.  Keep in mind that you can shorten a loop by using duplicates.size()-1.